# Can't start Minecraft server in tmux with systemctl

Tags: debian, tmux, systemd, minecraft, systemctl

I'm trying to automate my Minecraft server because having to manually wrangle tmux sessions gets really old after a while. Here's the systemd service file I wrote to help me with that:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server: %i
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/minecraft/servers/%i
User=minecraft
Group=minecraft

Restart=on-failure

ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new -s mc-%i -d '/usr/bin/java -Xms1G -Xmx6G -jar forge-universal.jar nogui' bash

ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux send -t mc-%i 'say SERVER WILL SHUT DOWN IN 10 SECONDS' ENTER
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 10
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux send -t mc-%i 'stop' ENTER

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Executing the `ExecStart` line manually works perfectly, the Java process is neatly put into a detached tmux session that I can attach to at my leisure.

Trying start the server via `systemctl start minecraft@creative` fails miserably, with dozens of error messages like these filling up the journal before finally failing:

```
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: Stopped Minecraft Server: private.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: Starting Minecraft Server: private...
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: Failed to start Minecraft Server: private.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: Stopped Minecraft Server: private.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: Starting Minecraft Server: private...
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: Started Minecraft Server: private.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: Stopped Minecraft Server: private.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: Failed to start Minecraft Server: private.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 11 21:34:45 kingcolour systemd[1]: minecraft@private.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Since tmux swallows all the error messages that could've happened, I have no idea what could be going wrong. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: please add the output of `journalctl -u minecraft@creative.service -b` to your question. please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1366001/edit) your question and do not respond in the comments.

Comment: Have added the last 20 lines of `journalctl` spam instead of just the last 7.

Comment: What is the point of the `bash` argument at the end? It looks like you're giving 2 different commands to tmux to run?

Comment: Goddammit. God flipping dammit. I was experimenting with different versions of the service file since none of them seemed to work, but I must've missed that part. Removing that errant `bash` makes the script work. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

systemd expects a service to stay running in the foreground in order to monitor it. When you run tmux detached, with `-d`, it forks a new process and returns the original command. I've not confirmed this with tmux and minecraft but try setting `Type=forking` in the `Service` section to tell systemd to track the child process forked from the command specified in `ExecStart`.

Side note: Are you sure you need tmux here? It's much simpler without.

Comment: Adding `Type=forking` didn't do anything, sadly. I'm getting the exact same error messages. And I do need tmux here. Starting Minecraft results in an interactive prompt that I need to administer the server.

Comment: Scratch that. This, combined with mjb2kmn's comment, made the script work. Thanks!